# How to retrieve coordinates of a vector coefficient meeting a certain criterion in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Given a vector of numbers, I would like to, for example, retrieve the coordinates `vector(i,j)` of all coefficients which are positive in order to further process the vector. What is MATLAB's syntax for this?

**Example**: For `[-1.143,0.089,2.654,4.142,]'` I would like to retrieve `[2,1;3,1;4,1]`

Comment: A vector numbers? Do you mean a large array containing many vectors? Do you want both i and j to be positive at the same time? Please show a typical input with the expected output.

Comment: A vector *of* numbers. I must apologise.

Answer (score 0):

```
%just some random data
M=rand(10,10)-.666
%get all indices which are positive, using logical indexing
positive_indices=M>0;
%get the positive data:
M(positive_indices)
%get the row and column index of the positive data
[r,c]=find(positive_indices)
```